# Update animated texture on plane when NOT selected?

Tags: texturing

I'm modeling a complex organic model guided by an animated texture as a reference.
This sequence updates fine as long as I only keep the textured plane selected. 
Unfortunately it freezes updating when NOT selected (on editing another mesh) and I'm scrolling through the timeline to check if everything is fine.
Is it possible in Blender to make the sequence on the *unselected* reference image plane update constantly?
I'm modeling in standard 3D-view in Blender 2.77a
TIA!

Comment: As far as I know Blender viewport materials are mostly optimized for speed, so unfortunately I don't think there is any sure way to maintain animated textures in the viewport. Not sure though

Comment: Instead of editing your question with the answer to your problem (along with adjusting the title), please instead post it as an answer (you can do that right below these comments).  Then the site will show that this question has an answer, which helps others find it.  Thank you.

Comment: Since you don't add your answer as solution, I did it for you. I also tested it and it still works in v2.79

Answer (score 1):

(Enhanced) Answer from OP moved here:

In **Object Mode** simply **Add -> Empty -> Image**

[image]

then open the desired movie or image sequence file(s) under the **Empty's Properties -> Data** 
[image]

set the source to **Match Movie Length** and **Auto Refresh**.

[image]

This way the sequence not only updates correctly when the Empty is selected but also, when working on another object!